# What exactly is contained within a obj.__closure__?

Tags: python, closures, python-internals

Beazley pg 100 mentions:

```
>>>python.__closure__
(<cell at 0x67f50: str object at 0x69230>,)
>>>python.__closure__[0].cell_contents
```

my understanding is that `__closure__` is a list but what's all this
cell stuff and str object?? That looks like a 1-ary tuple?

Comment: Recently I've written an answer to the question of why we get `"NameError: free variable 'var' referenced before assignment` error. I explained your question too if you wanna take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74336043/13944524

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Closure cells refer to values needed by the function but are taken from the surrounding scope.

When Python compiles a nested function, it notes any variables that it references but are only defined in a parent function (not globals) in the code objects for both the nested function and the parent scope. These are the `co_freevars` and `co_cellvars` attributes on the `__code__` objects of these functions, respectively.

Then, when you actually *create* the nested function (which happens when the parent function is executed), those references are then used to attach a closure to the nested function.

A function closure holds a tuple of cells, one each for each free variable (named in `co_freevars`); cells are special references to local variables of a parent scope, that follow the values those local variables point to. This is best illustrated with an example:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        print(spam)

    spam = 'ham'
    bar()
    spam = 'eggs'
    bar()
    return bar

b = foo()
b()
```

In the above example, the function `bar` has one closure cell, which points to `spam` in the function `foo`. The cell follows the value of `spam`. More importantly, once `foo()` completes and `bar` is returned, the cell continues to reference the value (the string `eggs`) even though the variable `spam` inside `foo` no longer exists.

Thus, the above code outputs:

```
>>> b=foo()
ham
eggs
>>> b()
eggs
```

and `b.__closure__[0].cell_contents` is `'eggs'`.

Note that the closure is dereferenced *when `bar()` is called*; the closure doesn't capture the value here. That makes a difference when you produce nested functions (with `lambda` expressions or `def` statements) that reference the loop variable:

```
def foo():
    bar = []
    for spam in ('ham', 'eggs', 'salad'):
        bar.append(lambda: spam)
    return bar

for bar in foo():
    print bar()
```

The above will print `salad` three times in a row, because all three `lambda` functions reference the `spam` variable, not the value it was bound to when the function object was created. By the time the `for` loop finishes, `spam` was bound to `'salad'`, so all three closures will resolve to that value.

Comment: Just an FYI that the order of elements in `__closure__` is arbitrary (hash table ordered). If you want to match the names of the free variables to their values, use a combination of `__code__.co_freevars` and `__closure__[<index>].cell_contents`. Index `i` `co_freevars` of the first corresponds to the index `i` of  `__closure__`.

Comment: @IllyaGerasymchuk: or, just use the [`inspect.getclosurevars()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getclosurevars), which combines the names for you.

Comment: @IllyaGerasymchuk Your comment says index i (read: i) of the first corresponds to index i` (read: i prime) of the second. Is the prime a typo? Should it be code.co_freevars[i] corresponds to __closure__[i]? Also, the following link mentions `__closure__`, `cell_content`, and `cell`: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

Comment: @joseville: the forward tick is a typo, it should be a backtick around `i` to mark that string as code. As a moderator I have the access to correct the comment, so I did.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "the closure is dereferenced when bar() is called; the closure doesn't capture the value here."  I have very little experience with dereferencing, and from I've just been reading online, it seems to me that "dereference" ***means*** to select the value held in memory at the address the reference points to, so your statement sounds contradictory to me. I'm hoping your elaboration would clear up my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 14):

It is the new Python 3 name for the old `func_closure`.

http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

> The function attributes named `func_X` have been renamed to use the `__X__` form, freeing up these names in the function attribute namespace for user-defined attributes. To wit, `func_closure`, `func_code`, `func_defaults`, `func_dict`, `func_doc`, `func_globals`, `func_name` were renamed to `__closure__`, `__code__`, `__defaults__`, `__dict__`, `__doc__`, `__globals__`, `__name__`, respectively.

In a nutshell:

`__closure__` is `None` or a `tuple` of cells that contain binding for the function's free variables.

Also, it is NOT writable.

Reference:https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

**Example** Python < 3 (so I am using `func_closure`)

```
def foo():
    x = "I am used"
    y = "I am free"
    z = "I am free too"

    def bar(x):
        return x, y, z

    return bar

c = foo().func_closure

print [i.cell_contents for i in c]
```

Output:

```
>>> 
['I am free', 'I am free too']
```

As `foo` is returning the function `bar` which is using its own value `x`, but not `y` or `z`. So, they come under `__closure__`.

Comment: The type.htlm link seems dead. Info about `__closure__` and cell contents can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

Answer (score 4):

when a nested function(`closure`) is defined in python:
the outer function uses `co_cellvars` to note variables defined in the outer function that could be referenced by inner function.
the inner function uses `co_freevars` to note variables defined in the outer function, which could be referenced for later use.

Example:

```
# python3
Python 3.4.5 (default, May 29 2017, 15:17:55) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def foo(n):
...     a = 1
...     def g(n):
...             return a - n
...     return g
... 
>>> foo.__closure__
>>> foo.__code__.co_freevars
()
>>> foo.__code__.co_cellvars
('a',)
>>> foo(0).__closure__
(<cell at 0x7f2cd98db1c8: int object at 0x7f2cd9847960>,)
>>> foo(0).__closure__[0].cell_contents
1
>>> foo(0).__code__.co_freevars
('a',)
>>> foo(0).__code__.co_cellvars
()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> def f():
...     a = "HELO"
...     b = 1.0
...     def w(c):
...         return a,b,c
...     return w

>>> w = f()
>>> w.__closure__
(<cell at 0xa05c4ac: str object at 0x9e91b74>, <cell at 0xa05c3bc: float object at 0xb733dde8>)
>>> w.__closure__[0].cell_contents
'HELO'
>>> w.__closure__[1].cell_contents
1.0
```

I have never seen the **cell** type used anywhere else. It seems to be purpose-built to hold closure variables.