# Where does the __closure__ attribute in python bound method come from?

Tags: python, closures

```
# python3
def foo(a):
    class A:
        def say(self):
            print(a)
    return A
A = foo(1)
'__closure__' in dir(A.say) # True
a = A()
a.say.__closure__ # it returns the closure tuple
'__closure__' in dir(a.say) # False
'__closure__' in dir(a.say.__class__) # False
'__closure__' in dir(a.say.__class__.__class__) # False
```

In Python3, A.say is a function, and I know it has**__closure__** attribute.
**__closure__** not in dir(a.say) or its super class, but a.say.**__closure__** returns the closure tuple. It makes me confuse. 
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413946/what-exactly-is-contained-within-a-obj-closure

Comment: @Styvane   thanks for your commit. They are not completely duplicate. The answer you provide tells how __closure works. I have edited my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know in Python the internal implementation of objects with type `instancemethod` but I think it is how **__getattr__** works in [instance method objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/method.html).

My guess is when you say **a.say.__closure__** it first looks up for __closure__ in **dir(a.say)** and then fallbacks on **dir(a.say.im_func)**.

```
>>> a = foo(1)()
>>> print type(a.say)
>>> instancemethod

>>> a.say.im_func.__closure__
>>> (<cell at 0x10a00f980: int object at 0x7fef29e098b8>,)

>>> '__closure__' in dir(a.say.im_func)
>>> True
```

Comment: thanks @ozgurv . My question is not very clear, and I have edited it. The **__closure__** attribute is in dir(inner_function). **__closure__** attribute is not in dir(a.say), but a.say.__closure__ does return the closure tuple. It makes me confuse. In fact, **__closure__** is in dir(A.say), because A.say is a function in Python3.

Comment: thanks. You are right. The **im_func** attribute is the original function object, and it's the original function object that contains the **__closure__** attribute.