# Nested function, lifetime of variable of outer function in python

Tags: python, function, closures, nested-function

```
def make(label): 
    def echo(message):
       print(label + ':' + message) 
    return echo

F = make('Spam')
F('Ham!') 
Spam:Ham!
```

My doubt here is that when `make` function exited, it returned the address of `echo` function. And now when we call `echo` function it still knows the `label` value. Since there is no `label` variable after `make` function exited. How did the `echo` function knows label value?

Comment: It does not "return the address of `echo` function".  It returns a function **object**.  That object has properties ... such as its closure.

Comment: The `label` variable is still alive after `make` returns, as long as there is a function around that still refers to it (such as `echo` (bound to `F`)).

Comment: I think you need to google for `python closure`, `label` will be alive until the `echo` lifecycle die.

Comment: this could be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413946/what-exactly-is-contained-within-a-obj-closure

Comment: A goodl artical: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure