# Python dereference closure variable at define-time

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-decorators

The answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413946/what-exactly-is-contained-within-a-obj-closure) details nicely how python inner functions don't use the value of closure variables until the inner function actually executes, finding the variable name in the proper scope.

For example:

```
funcs = [(lambda: x) for x in range(3)]
```

Calling any of the generated lambdas returns 2:

```py
>>> funcs[0]()
2
>>> funcs[1]()
2
>>> funcs[2]()
2
```

**Is there a way to force the value for x to be determined when the function is defined instead of when it is executed later?** In the above example, my desired output is 0, 1, 2, respectively.

More specifically, my use-case is to provide a way for API users to conveniently turn a custom function into a thread using a decorator. For example:

```
for idx in range(3):
    @thread_this(name=f'thread_{idx}')
    def custom():
        do_something()
        print(f'thread_{idx} complete.')
```

When the final print statement executes, it picks up whatever the *current* value of `idx` is in the global scope. With appropriate sleep statements, all 3 threads will print `'thread_2 complete.'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use functools.partial, first problem can be solved with,

```
funcs = [functools.partial(lambda x: x, x) for x in xrange(3)]
```

It will give you desired result.
However, I could not understand the second usecase.