# Get variable from a parent function

Tags: python

I have a function that produces another function.

```py
def make_func(greeting):
    def func(name):
        return greeting + " " + name
    return func

>>> say_hello = make_func("Hello")
>>> say_hello("there")
"Hello there"
```

Elsewhere in the script, I have access to `say_hello`, but I have no idea what the greeting in that function actually is. I'd like to find out.

`name`, of course, isn't possible to get because it's specified when the function is called. But `greeting is static`, because it's defined outside of the function.

Is there some attribute of `say_hello` I can examine to get the original `"Hello"`?

Comment: What is your Python version? A hacky way would be `say_hello.__closure__[0].cell_contents`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl For my specific case, I'm writing for 3.4 and up.

Comment: Why do you need this? See [What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

You can find a good explanation of how inner functions are compiled in python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14414638/7839649)

Then the easiest way to get the variable is `say_hello.__closure__[0].cell_contents`

Answer (score 1):

You can just store the attribute `greeting` in `func`:

```
def make_func(greeting):
    def func(name):
        return func.greeting + " " + name
    func.greeting = greeting
    return func

say_hello = make_func("Hello")
print(say_hello.greeting)  # Hello
say_hello.greeting = 'Bye'
print(say_hello('there'))  # Bye there
```