# How to access closed over variables given only the closure function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

In the following example:

```
def speak(volume):
    def whisper(text):
        print(text.lower() + ('.' * volume))
    def yell(text):
        print (text.upper() + ('!' * volume))
    if volume > 1:
        return yell
    elif volume <= 1:
        return whisper


func = speak(volume=10)
func('hello')
HELLO!!!!!!!!!! # <== obviously `10` is stored in `func` somewhere
```

Given `func`, how would I get the "volume"? Is there something within the `func` namespace which gives the value of `10`? I thought perhaps it would be in `func.__globals__` or `func.__dict__` but it's in neither.

Comment: You can always make `volume` variable global

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14414638/2958070 for usage of the `__closure__` attribute

Comment: the state variables might have been hidden for a reason. maybe it is not such a good idea to try to access them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Below (the code below return 10)

```
func.__closure__[0].cell_contents
```

Comment: thanks. What is a "cell object"? I've never come across that `type` before?

Comment: You better have a look here: https://gist.github.com/DmitrySoshnikov/700292