# Given a function with closure, can I refer back to it's closure scope?

Tags: python

I would like to refer to a function's closure scope:

```
class C():
    def d(self):
        def fn_class():
            return
        return fn_class

fn = C().d()
fn
# <function C.d.<locals>.fn_class at 0x0000025E8A381E18>
fn.__closure__
# None
```

All I want to do is that, given only `fn`, I want to reference back to `self`, `fn.__closure__` doesn't seem to work, I need some help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is correct but because `fn_class` doesn't pull in any information from `d` or `C`, `__closure__` has no information to give you so it is `None`.

Now, if you were to modify `d` like this:

```
def d(self):
    x = 5
    def fn_class():
        return x
    return fn_class
```

And then do:

```
fn = C().d()
fn
# <function C.d.<locals>.fn_class at 0x0000025E8A381E18>
fn.__closure__
# (<cell at 0x7fedb0a5be88: int object at 0x9a3180>,)
```

For more information, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413946/what-exactly-is-contained-within-a-obj-closure) question.

Now, with regard to your question, I don't think using `__closure__` will work because `self` isn't defined in a parent function - in this case, `d` - but is passed in from the outside. If you were to modify `d` so that you passed `self` in, like this:

```
def d(self):
    def fn_class(self):
        return
    return fn_class
```

Then, you could do:

```
fn.__code__.co_varnames
# ('self',)
```

but getting back to the actual location of `self` in that instance would be much more difficult.

Comment: Oh, I can totally see the problem, I am framework developer, function `fn_class` is written by other developers and the `fn_class` is passes to my framework, so I have no control over the content of `fn_class`. I need a more hacky way to do it.

Comment: If `fn_class` doesn't close over anything then it isn't a closure in the first place. [What problem are you actually trying to solve?](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Thanks for helping guys, I think I will enforce everyone to pass me the self also instead of doing anything hacky! Now everyone gotta change their codes.